# Change the output shape of Pytorch GAN Generator?

Tags: python, pytorch, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to build a GAN model that outputs sound, specifically the speech of the digits 0-9. I'm basing my GAN model on a conditional GAN used for the regular image MNIST dataset.

One of the main differences is that the shape of my data is 256x64, where as MNIST is 64x64. How can I modify the Generator to output 256x64? Can this be done by modifying the values of the Convtranspose2d layers? Or would it work to create a linear layer at the end of the sequential layer?

Do convolutional layers always need to be square? As in the dimensions need be the same value i.e. 64x64?

This is what the Generator looked like for the regular MNIST dataset:

```
class Generator(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, channels_noise, channels_img, features_g, num_classes, x1_size, x2_size, embed_size):
        super(Generator, self).__init__()
        self.x1_size = x1_size
        self.x1_size = x1_size
        self.net = nn.Sequential(
            # Input: N x channels_noise x 1 x 1
            self._block(channels_noise+embed_size, features_g * 16, 4, 1, 0),  # img: 4x4
            self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 8, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 8x8
            self._block(features_g * 8, features_g * 4, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 16x16
            self._block(features_g * 4, features_g * 2, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 32x32
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                features_g * 2, channels_img, kernel_size=4, stride=2, padding=1
                
            ),
            # Output: N x channels_img x 64 x 64
            nn.Tanh(),
        )
        self.embed = nn.Embedding(num_classes, embed_size)
    def _block(self, in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding):
        return nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(
                in_channels, out_channels, kernel_size, stride, padding, bias=False,
            ),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(out_channels),
            nn.ReLU(),
        )

    def forward(self, x, labels):
        # latent vector z = num_samples x noise_dim x 1 x 1
        embedding = self.embed(labels).unsqueeze(2).unsqueeze(3)
        x = torch.cat([x, embedding], dim=1) 
        return self.net(x).to(device)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do this - using a linear layer at the end of the sequential layer will work but it will be the equivalent of stretching a 64 x 64 output to a 256 x 64 output.

A more effective method would be to set the kernel size of the first convolutional layer so that the subsequent image resolutions are of the ratio 4N x N (since the expected resolution is (4*64) x (64) = 256 x 64). This can be done by defining the  initial layers as:

```
self._block(channels_noise+embed_size, features_g * 16, (4, 1), 1, 0), # img: 4x1
self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 16, 4, 1, 0), # 16x4
self._block(features_g * 16, features_g * 8, 4, 2, 1),  # img: 32x8
```